Query to find the records not created by the hierarchy
I have 3 tables allocation, demand and user. I want to find demand records that are not created by the hierarchical managers from the user id present in the allocation table.



Allocation table
Demand table
User table




allocation_id
demand_id
user_id


demand_id
project_id
manager_user_id


user_id
created_by_user_id
username


created_by_user_id
created_by_date
first_name


created_by_date

last_name



I tried with the below query but it doesn't work
select * from netapprm.demand d,netapprm.allocations a
where d.demand_id = a.demand_id
and a.created_by_user_id not in
(
with recursive q as (
  SELECT
emplid,n_nt_login, 0 as level, supervisor_id 
FROM netapprm.emp_details_temp WHERE emplid::bigint in (a.user_id)
  union all
  select
   b.emplid,b.n_nt_login, q.level+1, b.supervisor_id 
  from netapprm.emp_details_temp b
  join q on q.supervisor_id =b.emplid
) select
  string_agg(emplid::bigint, ',')
from q 
order by
  level)

Please suggest.
Thanks,
Aditya

Please spend a few minuets to Take the Tour and review [ask]. Then update your question to include table definition(s) (DDL), sample data, and expected results. All as formatted text or even better a fiddle, but - no images.
